# HTML5 video - doesn't work with mozilla firefox for mac

Tags: html, firefox, video, embed, mozilla

I've tried everything but the video doesn't start in Mozilla Firefox (running ot mac) neither do the controls work. But it works perfectly in every other browser and OS.
Please, help me! :(

**I wrote this:**

```
   <button id="play-pause-button" class="pp_button "></button>
   <button id="mute-button" class="m_button "></button>
 <script>
    $('#play-pause-button').click(function () {
   if ($("video").get(0).paused) {
       $("video").get(0).play();
   } else {
       $("video").get(0).pause();
  }
});


     $('#mute-button').click(function () {
   $("video").prop('muted', true);

   if( $("video").prop('muted', true) )
        {
            $("video").prop('muted', false)
        }
                $("#mute-button").click( function (){
    $("video").prop('muted', !$("video").prop('muted'));
});
  });


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("video").prop('muted', true);

    $("video").click( function (){
        if( $("video").prop('muted', true) )
        {
            $("video").prop('muted', false)
        }
        $("video").click( function (){
    $(this).prop('muted', !$(this).prop('muted'));
});
    });
});



 </script>

  <script>

  </script>
  <div id="container1">

    <video autoplay loop muted>

        <source src="//player.vimeo.com/external/109280665.hd.mp4?s=f907d6edd960998ede2030e9c03fc641" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="//player.vimeo.com/external/109280665.hd.mp4?s=f907d6edd960998ede2030e9c03fc641" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div class="content1">

    </div>

</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: have you checked in developer console to see what errors you are getting in Firefox? I notice both your mp4 and webm are pointing at an mp4 source...

Comment: I made a research and found that many developers have this problem. But didn't find any solution... I didn't find any errors. I've tried to convert the video in ogg & webm and nothing happened. :(

Comment: In the Firefox console I see it saying it doesn't support video/mp4 (expected), you can't change the Vimeo file simply by changing the type in your browser, but ... your code, in a working example, pointing at a tested webm file working in Firefox on OSX - http://jsfiddle.net/vf42qndz/1/